# Opportunity Territory Assignment in Progress... forever

Tags: apex, territory-management

I've just setup Enterprise Territory Management for a very simple org (1 type, 8 territories). Accounts assignment rules work fine but I'm struggling to get opportunity territory assignment working. I'm using what seems to be the defacto Apex class, my code is [here](https://github.com/dgrstl/apex), but when I run it I get this indicator on the model hierarchy but never get a confirmation email:

> Opportunity territory assignment is currently in progress. The process may take several hours. We'll send you an email when it's done.

I've tried this in both my sandbox (let it run overnight) and production (been running about an hour) with the same result. Bear in mind, this org has less than 200 total opportunities (all time).

While this process is running, should I start to see opportunities being assigned to territories (assuming the code is good, of course)? Or would I only see this once the job completes? I ask because I periodically run a report of opportunities by territory and never see any assignment.

Finally, how can I debug this process?

```
/*** Apex version of the default logic.
* If opportunity's assigned account is assigned to
*  Case 1: 0 territories in active model
*            then set territory2Id = null
*  Case 2: 1 territory in active model
*            then set territory2Id = account's territory2Id
*  Case 3: 2 or more territories in active model
*            then set territory2Id = account's territory2Id that is of highest priority.
*            But if multiple territories have same highest priority, then set territory2Id = null 
*/
global class OppTerrAssignDefaultLogicFilter implements TerritoryMgmt.OpportunityTerritory2AssignmentFilter { 
    /**
     * No-arg constructor.
     */ 
     global OppTerrAssignDefaultLogicFilter() {}

     /**
      * Get mapping of opportunity to territory2Id. The incoming list of opportunityIds contains only those with IsExcludedFromTerritory2Filter=false.
      * If territory2Id = null in result map, clear the opportunity.territory2Id if set.
      * If opportunity is not present in result map, its territory2Id remains intact.
      */
    global Map<Id,Id> getOpportunityTerritory2Assignments(List<Id> opportunityIds) { 
        Map<Id, Id> OppIdTerritoryIdResult = new Map<Id, Id>();

        // Get the active territory model Id
        Id activeModelId = getActiveModelId();

        if(activeModelId != null){
            List<Opportunity> opportunities =
              [Select Id, AccountId, Territory2Id from Opportunity where Id IN :opportunityIds];
            Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
            // Create set of parent accountIds
            for(Opportunity opp:opportunities){
                if(opp.AccountId != null){
                    accountIds.add(opp.AccountId);
                    }
                }

                Map<Id,Territory2Priority> accountMaxPriorityTerritory = getAccountMaxPriorityTerritory(activeModelId, accountIds);

            // For each opportunity, assign the highest priority territory if there is no conflict, else assign null.
            for(Opportunity opp: opportunities){
               Territory2Priority tp = accountMaxPriorityTerritory.get(opp.AccountId);
               // Assign highest priority territory if there is only 1.
                if(tp != null) {
                //&& (tp.moreTerritoriesAtPriority == false) && (tp.territory2Id != opp.Territory2Id)){
                   OppIdTerritoryIdResult.put(opp.Id, tp.territory2Id);
                }else{
                   OppIdTerritoryIdResult.put(opp.Id, null);
               }
            }
        }
        return OppIdTerritoryIdResult;
    }

    /**
      * Query assigned territoryIds in active model for given accountIds.
      * Create a map of accountId to max priority territory.
      */
     private Map<Id,Territory2Priority> getAccountMaxPriorityTerritory(Id activeModelId, Set<Id> accountIds){
        Map<Id,Territory2Priority> accountMaxPriorityTerritory = new Map<Id,Territory2Priority>();
        for(ObjectTerritory2Association ota:[Select ObjectId, Territory2Id, Territory2.Territory2Type.Priority from ObjectTerritory2Association where objectId IN :accountIds and Territory2.Territory2ModelId = :activeModelId]){
            Territory2Priority tp = accountMaxPriorityTerritory.get(ota.ObjectId);

            if((tp == null) || (ota.Territory2.Territory2Type.Priority > tp.priority)){
                // If this is the first territory examined for account or it has greater priority than current highest priority territory, then set this as new highest priority territory.
                tp = new Territory2Priority(ota.Territory2Id,ota.Territory2.Territory2Type.priority,false);
            }else if(ota.Territory2.Territory2Type.priority == tp.priority){
                // The priority of current highest territory is same as this, so set moreTerritoriesAtPriority to indicate multiple highest priority territories seen so far.
                tp.moreTerritoriesAtPriority = true;
            }

            accountMaxPriorityTerritory.put(ota.ObjectId, tp);
        }
        return accountMaxPriorityTerritory;
    }


    /**
     * Get the Id of the Active Territory Model.
     * If none exists, return null.
     */
    private static Id getActiveModelId() {
        List<Territory2Model> models = [Select Id from Territory2Model where State = 'Active'];
        Id activeModelId = null;
        if(models.size() == 1){
            activeModelId = models.get(0).Id;
        }

        return activeModelId;
    }

    /**
    * Helper class to help capture territory2Id, its priority, and whether there are more territories with same priority assigned to the account.
    */
    @TestVisible
    global class Territory2Priority {
        public Id territory2Id { get; set; }
        public Integer priority { get; set; }
        public Boolean moreTerritoriesAtPriority { get; set; }

        @TestVisible
        Territory2Priority(Id territory2Id, Integer priority, Boolean moreTerritoriesAtPriority){
            this.territory2Id = territory2Id;
            this.priority = priority;
            this.moreTerritoriesAtPriority = moreTerritoriesAtPriority;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your code is not too long, please include it here as well. You can format it using the `{}` button in your editor, or hit `CTRL + K`.

Comment: So my code did finally complete but I"m not sure why it failed.

"Your request to run opportunity territory assignment filter for Current Fiscal Year has failed. Please try again."

Comment: Please **[edit]** this question to include your code *here*.